# Could we merge tags 'navigation-mesh' and 'navmesh'?

Tags: discussion, tags

The title says it all.

These two are describing the exact same thing, so I suggest we only keep one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even though [navigation-mesh](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation-mesh) is more wordy and describe more exactly what it is, users will not be confused by the term [navmesh](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navmesh) as it's very commonly used.

I suggest we make [navigation-mesh](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation-mesh) a synonym of [navmesh](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navmesh) because *navmesh* is shorter to write, has no hyphen, and is sooo much cooler :P

Comment: Looks like Josh [synonymed them](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/navmesh/synonyms) yesterday—edit to mention that and mark accepted?

Comment: Oh yeah, I did and forgot to comment here.